# Staring blankly at

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, expressions

I have a few question that I hope you can help me with.

Monica is sitting on the couch staring blankly at the TV. She snaps out of it, grabs the remote, and turns off the TV.

- Can I use "staring blankly at" to tell that Monica is staring at the TV without really watching what is showed because she's lost in thought or is there a better word than "blankly" to say that?
- Is it natural to use "snaps out of it" here to mean that she wakes up from being lost in thought?
- "Snaps out of it" seems very sudden, is there a milder expression to say the same but just less sudden or is "snaps out of it" the best option?

I hope you can understand my questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is three questions.  Please ask each one separately as then each can be answered and voted upon separately.

Answer (score 1):

"Staring blankly" means staring with a 'blank expression' on one's face. It *could* mean that they were not concentrating on the television, but it could also mean that they are so engrossed in what is on the television they have lost all expression.

A similar expression that specifically means looking at nothing is "staring into space", or the less common "staring into the middle distance".

"Snaps out of it" is perfectly idiomatic and makes sense in your example. A more gentle expression that means leaving a sleep-like state gradually is "*coming to*".

Comment: @ReinstateMonica It's in just about every dictionary but I agree it isn't used as much as your suggestion so I'll add that in.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that “snaps out of it” is too sudden, because “it” has yet to be defined. It makes sense in a very casual sense, but to me doesn’t feel quite right in this (what I assume to be creative writing) context.

Perhaps you could solve both problems (the other problem being the lack of detail in “staring blankly”) in a somewhat cataphoric way by saying something like:

> Monica is sitting on the couch staring blankly at the TV. She snaps out of her reverie, grabs the remote, and turns off the TV.